# Can you use a variable with cos()

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I've been trying to find this for a while and can't figure it out. I've narrowed the error in my code to this, and whatever I try it didn't work. What I want to know is for example:

```
var test = 1 
var test2 = cos(test)
print(test2)
```

When I do this, it simply returns as NaN. But if I only do this:

```
var test3 = cos(1)
print(test3)
```

It returns the number I expect to see. So can you replace the integer with a variable? For context this is JS with the p5.Js library.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you please post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Ok so I was able to fix the problem by simply adding Math. to the beggining of cos(). It then started returning what I needed. I also believe one of the variables was returning "undefined", which might of caused it as well.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't properly loaded the p5.js library.